# Node: Search for a filetype in a folder

Tags: file, node.js

I wonder what's the best way to search for template files that has the format `*.tmpl.*` like `comment.tmpl.dot`in Node and take the content of the file and execute it as a parameter in a callback?

Answer (score 1):

My basic plan would be

1. Read the directory
2. Use a regex to match your filename pattern
3. Read the file and do whatever you need to it

Here is some code to get you started, and here is the filesystem API in NodeJs http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
    sourcePath = '/your path/'; 

    var files = fs.readdirSync(sourcePath);

    for (var f in files){
        var file = files[f];

        if (file.match(/.*\.tmpl\..*/) {

            // do whatever you want e.g. read the file
            fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
                 if (err) throw err;
                 console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't think so. I'm pretty sure it takes a filename and returns the content of that file in the callback. Nothing cleverer than that